# How to send values greater 127 in byte array thru outputstream

Tags: java, arrays

This is my hex string :

```
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
```

After converting this hex string to byte array with below code, I am getting some values in negative.

This is because byte in java is signed (-127 to 127). **Agreed !**

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) 
{
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
}
```

Because of negative values my request is failing and I am saying this because when i send values <= 127 my request works fine.

If i send hard code values like this than if works fine.

```
byte arr[] = new byte[] {1,49,45,1,2,(byte)214,1,1,98,0,6,0,0,9,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,127,(byte)255,0,21,0,16,0,75,1,0,0,58,32,2,7,0,0,4,4,0,85,81,98,0,5,14,(byte)158,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,88,82,50,69,49,83,49,86,48,67,48,0,0,1,97,75,0,84,30,12,7,17,5,7,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,6,0,0,48,49,48,48,49,48,51,48,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,70,48,10,29,22,85,0,1,(byte)134,(byte)160,(byte)255,(byte)255,(byte)158,(byte)170,0,0,0,67,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,12,0,12,0,12,0,12,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,12,0,12,0,12,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,2,(byte)158,2,(byte)159,2,(byte)241,2,(byte)234,5,48,5,68,8,90,7,(byte)193,6,15,4,10,3,100,4,(byte)224,7,47,6,72,4,(byte)170,4,4,4,7,5,16,6,107,6,114,5,(byte)195,4,(byte)179,2,(byte)198,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,101,0,99,0,(byte)129,0,(byte)129,2,81,2,(byte)224,1,(byte)153,0,(byte)30,0,31,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,21,0,86,0,98,0,51,0,72,0,104,0,(byte)144,0,(byte)175,0,(byte)174,0,(byte)174,2,20,4,(byte)132,4,103,5,96,0,126,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,15,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,85,1,41,1,104,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,14,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,12,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,14,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,13,0,(byte)226,0,(byte)223,0,(byte)223,0,15,0,14,0,13,0,115,0,(byte) 223,(byte)162,40,38,85,115,101,114,78,97,109,101,61,101,82,101,103,38,85,115,101,114,80,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,61,97,98,99,49,50,51};
```

I am sending the byte array as

```
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(arr);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

So I need some work around where i can send 214 as byte in the outputStream.
Since 'D6' in byte represents -42 and I want to send 214 (-42+256) in the byte array.

My complete code is as follows :

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) 
    {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String str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
    byte arr[] = convertHexToString(str);



    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {

        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

    URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(arr);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println("POST Response Code : " + responseCode);
    System.out.println("Response Message : " + con.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println("Content Encoding : " + con.getContentEncoding());
    System.out.println("Content Length : " + con.getContentLength());
    System.out.println("Content Type : " + con.getContentType());
    System.out.println("URL : " + con.getURL());
    System.out.println("Content : " + con.getContent().toString());
    System.out.println(con.getContent());


}
```

Comment: "Because of negative values i am getting response as 500." - what are you talking about?

Comment: What is the point of "**Agreed !**"?

Comment: What you need to do is find out what causes the internal server error. The so called "negative" values have nothing to do with it.

Comment: byte in java can have -127 to 127 as value. so I agree that on converting D6 to byte I will get -42 and not 214.

Comment: `System.out.println((byte)214 == (byte)-42)` prints `true`, the output stream treats them as the same when sending

Comment: What is being done, is not a POST. I would go back a step. The bytes were okay. Though generally one cannot take a String from a byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the HTTP response code 500 is quite likely not the negative values in a byte array. These values are automatically converted to an unsigned value during the process of sending it to the server.

You most likely created an invalid HTTP-request. What exactly went wrong is hard to tell with the little number of source lines you provided, but assuming that `con` is an `HTTPUrlConnection` what you should send is url encoded content as key-value-pairs (the same what you see in an URL after the `?`.

To find out what really went wrong, check the server's log to see the server's error message about the reason of the "Internal Server Error".

Comment: They're not converted. Signedness depends entirely on how you interpret the bits. If someone says "here's a signed byte `0xFF`" it's `-1`, if someone says "here's an unsigned byte `0xFF`" it's `255`.

Comment: @Kayaman In lack of a better word, I used "converted" but you're right.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "interpreted": "interpreted as signed" or "interpreted as unsigned"